# Are there electrical outlets in the sleeper cars of the California Zephyr?

Tags: usa, trains, power, amtrak

I will be taking the [California Zephyr](http://www.seat61.com/california-zephyr.htm) the entire journey, and I planned on getting a lot of work done on my laptop during the journey. I will be staying in a roomette, I've taken Amtrak on the North East Corrider, both coach and [Acela](http://www.amtrak.com/servlet/ContentServer/AM_Route_C/1241245664867/1237405732511)  before and I know that coach and business class Acela have outlets. However, I can't find outlets in this 3-D Panoramic of [a California Zephyr Roomette](http://www.360cities.net/image/amtrak-roomette-sleeper-california-zephyr-2007#41.70,39.92,32.6).

Will I be able to charge my laptop during this 52 hour journey?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to this image atleast:
http://www.360cities.net/image/amtrak-roomette-sleeper-california-zephyr-2007#424.41,0.66,20.0

http://www.360cities.net/image/amtrak-roomette-sleeper-california-zephyr-2007#424.41,0.66,20.0">[image]

if you look into the other room http://www.360cities.net/image/amtrak-roomette-sleeper-california-zephyr-2007#553.27,12.12,20.0 you can even see a a macbook beeing charged.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

I traveled on the California Zephyr in January 2010 and had a roomette.  It does indeed have an outlet.  As I recall, it had a label saying something like "Razor Only" but worked fine to charge my laptop.  It might not work for higher-current appliances.

Comment: I just zoomed that web page in and yep, it says 120V - RAZOR ONLY under the plug. A tip from airline power that resets when you draw too much - charge the laptop with the lid closed at times you're not using it (during meals, while you're sleeping etc) and use it on battery. Often makes the difference between tripping the breaker and not.

Answer (score 4):

Just to confirm, when I took the trip in December 2011, there was a 120 volt outlet that said "Razor Only" However, it charged my nook, laptop and two phones without issue.

Comment: Roomettes have one outlet, bedrooms have two.  When traveling by roomette, if I remember to I bring along a short extension cord.  I have never had a problem charging two devices at once (e.g. laptop and iPhone).