# Are there electrical outlets in Amtrak California Zephyr bedrooms?

Tags: trains, power, sleeping, amtrak

How many electrical outlets are there in a bedroom on the California Zephyr? Where are they located? Any photos showing this?

Comment: If they didn't change the layout much from 10 years ago...: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3660/are-there-electrical-outlets-in-the-sleeper-cars-of-the-california-zephyr

Comment: @xngtng: That's for a roomette though.  Bedrooms are a different type of room.

Comment: @NateEldredge Yes (why I didn't mark it as duplicate), although I believe as far as the seat goes, the outlet should be in the same position for non-suite Bedroom.

Comment: Why is teh number and location important?  What perceived problem do you think you will have?